# Adding Sound To Random Image

Tags: swift, audio

I am currently making an App for my grandson who has been diagnosed with Autism.  One of the games I am putting on the app is a simple flash card game.  Hit the button it produces a random image with a letter.  I want add sound to the random image.  example  if image A appears the sound for letter A happens.  I know how to add the sound to a file, just not sure how to figure out how to get the sound to match the random image.  Here is my code.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Say_It_VC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var imageOne: UIImageView!

    let imageNames = ["A3","B3","C3","D3","E3","F3","G3","H3","I3","J3","K3","L3","M3","N3","O3","P3","Q3","R3","S3","T3","U3","V3","W3","X3","Y3","Z3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

}
    @IBAction func showImages(_ sender: Any) {


        let leftNumber:Int = Int (arc4random_uniform(26))

        imageOne.image = UIImage (named: imageNames[leftNumber])

    }

}
```